# crop image and save it to gallery

Tags: ionic2

i want to select image from gallery ,crop it and save cropped image to gallery as a file.

i used camera native but i can't save it to my gallery again

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
     quality: 100,
     sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
     destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
     encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
     mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
     //allowEdit: true
   }
   this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
     this.base64Image = "data:image/JPEG;base64,"+imageData;
     //this.path =this.base64Image.toDataURL;
     console.log("path ",this.base64Image);
    //resolve(this.base64Image);

   }, (err) => {
       console.log("error",err)
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the file yourself using `cordova-plugin-file`. Here is some instruction on how to do so:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/150/how-to-create-an-image-file-from-a-base64-string-on-the-device-with-cordova